# PHP Read/Write files on remote server

Tags: php, file, remote-server, read-write

I'm making a utility that provides a GUI to easy edit certain values in a csv file on a remote server. My boss wants the utility in php running on the private webserver. I'm new to php, but I was able to get the GUI file modifier working locally without issues. The final piece now is rather than the local test file I need to grab a copy of the requested file off of the remote server, edit it, and then replace the old file with the edited one. My issue is uploading and downloading the file.

When I searched for a solution I found the following:
(note in each of these I am just trying to move a test file)

```
$source = "http://<IP REMOTE SERVER>/index.html";
$dest = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."index.html";
copy($source, $dest);
```

This solution ran into a permissions error.

```
$source ="http://<IP REMOTE SERVER>/index.html";
$destination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."newfile.html";

$data = file_get_contents($source);

$handle = fopen($destination, "w");

fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
```

This also had a permissions error

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('<IP REMOTE SERVER>', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'cahenk', '<PASSWORD>');
ssh2_scp_recv($connection, '/tmp/CHenk/CHenk.csv', 'Desktop/CHenk.csv');
```

This solution has the error Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() which I have learned is because the function is not a part of the default php installation.

In closing, is there any easy way to read/write files to the remote server through php either by changing permissions, having the php extension installed, or a different way entirely that will work. Basically I'm trying to find the solution that requires the least settings changes to the server because I am not the administrator and would have to go through a round about process of getting any changes done. If something does need to be changed instructions on doing so or a link to instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just install the [SSH2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.setup.php) extension (with openssl and libssh2)? Alternatively, can you create a "mapped drive" of sorts, allowing you to read/write files as if they were local?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `enable-url-fopen-wrapper` in your php.ini?(only if your php version is older)

Please look @ [php remote files storing in example 2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php)